# Order data with custom filter inside of ng-repeat directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have data like this :

```
{
  games":[
     {
      "id":"AAA",
      "name":"Joker Double Up",
     },
     {
        "id":"BBB",
        "name":"Joker Wild Up",
     },
     {
        "id":"CCC",
       "name":"Joker Wild Double Up",
     },
     {
        "id":"DDD",
        "name":"Wild Double Up",
     },
     {
        "id":"EEE",
        "name":"Joker Wild Double",
     }
  ]
}
```

(its come from back end ,so i cant do edit here) , and show it in ng-repeat.

I want to order this data like this

```
var order =  ['CCC' , 'AAA' , 'BBB' , 'EEE' , 'DDD'] //from CCC to DDD
```

( its has not any logical statement , just custom order )

How can i write this rules for my orderBy function ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For that case, you need to write a custom filter. Here you can view more details how to implement: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: If you don't have a logical order, don't use order by, even, you could show each array position instead of use a `ng-repeat`. E.g: `<span>{{::data.games[2].name}}</span><span>{{::data.games[0].name}}</span>`... If the order of the back end can change, just find it by id property. I can provide an example to you if you want...

Comment: Hi @The.Bear , in really i have more then 2000 items , and only for that use ng-repeat .

Comment: But in these 2000 items, have you only five id's? From 'AAA' to 'EEE'? Or you have to sort it alphabetically and you just want to change the first 5 letters order?

Comment: Already yes , 2000 items has only 5 id's ,and i need to order all this items like here -->'CCC' , 'AAA' , 'BBB' , 'EEE' , 'DDD' , not alphabetically .

Comment: Example . CCC,CCC,CCC,CCC,AAA,AAA,AAA,BBB,BBB,EEE,EEE,EEE,EEE,EEE,DDD,DDD,DDD,DDD,DDD ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have problems with performance, you should not use `| filter`, because it will be executed at each `$digest` cycle. You should call `orderFn` manually, when array or sorting rules are changed. At case of 3k rows time of sorting about 2s.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var data = {
      "games":[
       {
        "id":"AAA",
        "name":"Joker Double Up",
       },
       {
          "id":"BBB",
          "name":"Joker Wild Up",
       },
       {
          "id":"CCC",
         "name":"Joker Wild Double Up",
       },
       {
          "id":"DDD",
          "name":"Wild Double Up",
       },
       {
          "id":"EEE",
          "name":"Joker Wild Double",
       }
    ]
  };
  
  var input = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 600; i++)
    input = input.concat(data.games);
  var order =  ['CCC' , 'AAA' , 'BBB' , 'EEE' , 'DDD'];
  
  function orderFn(array, order){
     return array.sort(function(a, b){
      return order.indexOf(a.id) - order.indexOf(b.id);
    });
  }
  
  console.time('orderFn');
  $scope.output = orderFn(input, order);
  var a = console.timeEnd('orderFn');
  
}])
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyController">
   <li ng-repeat='game in output track by $index'>{{game | json}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom sort to get the order , if you dont want to change existing array , you can define custom filter as  below in Angular , hope this helps

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCrtl", function($scope) {
  $scope.games = [{
    "id": "AAA",
    "name": "Joker Double Up"
  }, {
    "id": "BBB",
    "name": "Joker Wild Up"
  }, {
    "id": "CCC",
    "name": "Joker Wild Double Up"
  }, {
    "id": "CCC",
    "name": "Joker Wild Double Up1"
  }, {
    "id": "DDD",
    "name": "Wild Double Up"
  }, {
    "id": "AAA",
    "name": "Joker Double Up"
  }, {
    "id": "EEE",
    "name": "Joker Wild Double"
  }];
}).filter("myOrder", function() {

  return function(input) {
    input.sort(function(a, b) {

      function getNumber(str) {
        switch (str) {
          case "CCC":
            return 1
          case "AAA":
            return 2
          case "BBB":
            return 3
          case "EEE":
            return 4
          case "DDD":
            return 5
        }

      }
      return getNumber(a.id) - getNumber(b.id);
    });
    return input
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCrtl">

  <div ng-repeat="game in games | myOrder">

    {{game}}

  </div>


  <body>
```